# E value different in C and Kotlin Math.exp

Tags: java, android, c, kotlin, math

I am converting C Code to Java(kotlin) for a Android app

In C I get

```
printf("\\n  e value :%f \\n", 1.0e-4);
    e value :0.000100
```

In Android Studio

```
System.out.println("e value "+ 1*Math.exp(-4));

Output
e value 0.01831563888873418
```

Any idea why? C language code is the working code i found.. i need to get the same result with kotlin

Comment: Why don't you read the doco for the function `exp()`? While you're there, check into something like `pow()`...

Comment: You're computing two completely different things and get two completely different results

Comment: For the C version, you want `printf("%f\n", pow(M_E, -4));` ... remember to `#include <math.h>`

Comment: @pmg "_converting C Code to Java_"... The C version is probably the starting point...

Comment: `1*Math.exp(-4)` is not the same thing as `1.0e-4` (in fact, the equivalent in Java is also `1.0e-4`).

Answer (score 1):

In C, `1.0e-4` denotes 1.0•10<sup>−4</sup>.

In Kotlin, `Math.exp(-4)` denotes *e*<sup>−4</sup>, where *e* is [Euler’s number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), approximately 2.718281828459.

In Kotlin, you can use `1e-4` or `1.0e-4` for 10<sup>−4</sup>. Note the exact value used in computation will differ slightly from 10<sup>−4</sup> because the input text is converted to a floating-point format that uses base two.